# GPflow Predictive Mean/Variance for Poisson Likelihood

Tags: gpflow

Context: I trained a model using SVGP with a Poisson Likelihood (and a log/exp link).
Aside from predicting the counts, I'd like to have an uncertainty measure .

The function `m.predict_y` provides both the predictive mean and predictive variance. With a **Poisson likelihood**, it's using the default implementation of `Likelihood.predict_mean_and_var`with Gauss-Hermite quadrature.

Is this calculating the expectations of the counts (i.e. our target/dependent variable), or of the poisson parameter?

- (i) If it is predictive mean/variance of the poisson parameter, how would one use this variance to get meaningful credible intervals?
- (ii) If it is the predictive mean/var of the counts, shouldn't the mean be identical to the variance (since we integrate out everything but y and y is poisson distributed)? Or am I misunderstanding the concept of predictive variance?

If I understand the code correctly, we get the predictive mean/variance of the poisson parameter (i).

In my current approach I rewrote `predict_mean_and_var` so that it uses the mcmc method `ndiag_mc_perc` instead of the hermite-gauss  approximation and then just returning the 10%/90% percentiles of the samples.

Comment: Not a *programming* question, hence arguably off-topic here; better suited for [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: It is a question regarding the implementation of gpflow.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: `predict_y` predicts mean and variance of *y*, which is always in the observation space, i.e. the same space in which the `Y` live that you pass to the model constructor. In this case, it is the mean and variance of the counts, your second point (ii). For a Poisson distribution, mean and variance are always the same (equal to the intensity) *given the intensity*, i.e. conditioned on the value of the latent GP *f*; there will be a minor discrepancy between mean and variance returned by `predict_y` for a Poisson likelihood model due to integrating out the uncertainty in *f*.

It only really makes sense to talk about uncertainty in the intensity though if you have multiple *observations*, but in the Poisson likelihood as implemented in GPflow one `Y` constitutes a *single* observation (because each observation contains generally many events). You can build a likelihood that knows about multiple observations, and then you see a reduction in uncertainty for more observations as you would expect.

(If your count variance is *not* equal to the count expectation, you may want to consider under- or over-dispersed count likelihoods such as negative binomial or others.)

Comment: But when looking at the code, the integrand function is the conditional mean, i.e. just the link function.

So predict_mean_and_var returns the integral 
\int link(f) p(f)df , with p(f)=N(Fmu, Fvar)
but I don't really see the integration over y happening?

Comment: Okay nevermind I just got it, the conditional mean is already the expectation of y conditioned on one sample from the GP, so we only have to integrate out the GP.

thanks